# Looping on register results gives "template error while templating string: unexpected '*'"

Tags: windows, ansible

I want to get the state of two account from a registered results and rename them but Ansible gives error when looping over that register.

The variable I am looping on is:

```yaml
user_accounts:
  - old_name: account1
    new_name: account11
  - old_name: account2
    new_name: account22
```

I look the accounts up.

```yaml
- name: get the state of the users account
  win_user:
    name: "{{ item.old_name }}"
    state: query 
  loop: "{{ user_accounts }}"
  register: accounts_to_rename

- name: debug
  debug:
    var: accounts_to_rename
```

The debug results:

```json
{
   "accounts_to_rename":{
      "changed":false,
      "msg":"All items completed",
      "results":[
         {
            "ansible_loop_var":"item",
            "changed":false,
            "failed":false,
            "invocation":{
               "module_args":{
                  "account_disabled":null,
                  "account_locked":null,
                  "description":null,
                  "fullname":null,
                  "groups":null,
                  "groups_action":"replace",
                  "home_directory":null,
                  "login_script":null,
                  "name":"account1",
                  "password":null,
                  "password_expired":null,
                  "password_never_expires":null,
                  "profile":null,
                  "state":"query",
                  "update_password":"always",
                  "user_cannot_change_password":null
               }
            },
            "item":{
               "old_name":"account1",
               "new_name":"account11"
            },
            "name":"account1",
            "state":"present"
         },
         {
            "ansible_loop_var":"item",
            "changed":false,
            "failed":false,
            "invocation":{
               "module_args":{
                  "account_disabled":null,
                  "account_locked":null,
                  "description":null,
                  "fullname":null,
                  "groups":null,
                  "groups_action":"replace",
                  "home_directory":null,
                  "login_script":null,
                  "name":"account2",
                  "password":null,
                  "password_expired":null,
                  "password_never_expires":null,
                  "profile":null,
                  "state":"query",
                  "update_password":"always",
                  "user_cannot_change_password":null
               }
            },
            "item":{
               "old_name":"account2",
               "new_name":"account22"
            },
            "name":"account2",
            "state":"present"
         }
      ],
      "skipped":false
   }
}
```

Then, I want to:

- rename `account1` to `account11`
- rename `account2` to `account22`

This is based on the state of the old account:

```yaml
- name: W2K19.319_L1_Rename_administrator_account
  win_shell: "Rename-LocalUser -Name '{{ item.old_name }}' -NewName '{{ item.new_name }}'"
  loop: "{{ user_accounts | flatten(1) }}"
  when: accounts_to_rename.results[*].state == present
```

The error I get:

> "msg": "The conditional check 'accounts_to_rename.results[*].state == present' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected '*'.

Without the `[*]`, Ansible gives:

> "msg": "The conditional check 'accounts_to_rename.results.state == present' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (accounts_to_rename.results.state == present): 'list object' has no attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Rather loop on `accounts_to_rename` and access the new name via its `item.item.new_name` attribute.

So:

```yaml
- name: W2K19.319_L1_Rename_administrator_account
  win_shell: >-
    Rename-LocalUser 
      -Name '{{ item.name }}' 
      -NewName '{{ item.item.new_name }}'
  loop: "{{ accounts_to_rename.results }}"
  when: item.state == 'present'
```